# Jquery Cycle plugin menu hover effect automatic start

Tags: jquery, menu, hover, autostart

I'm trying to create a menu driver slideshow with the Jquery Cycle plugin http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/ but I can't figure out how to make it work properly. It puts numbers on the nav? I also want it to cycle automatically but stop when the menu item is hovered over.

I want it to work in a similar to this plugin (note I can't use this as it is mootools which conflicts with other jquery)
http://www.devthought.com/wp-content/projects/mootools/barackslideshow/Demo/

This is my code I'm implementing

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cycle.all.2.72v2.js.gz"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#slideshow').cycle({
        speed:       200,
        timeout:     0,
        pager:      '#nav',
        pagerEvent: 'mouseover',
        activePagerClass: 'activeSlide', // class name used for the active pager element
    });
});
</script>

<div id="nav">
        <a href="#">test1</a>
        <a href="#">test2</a>
        <a href="#">test3</a>
        <a href="#">test4</a>
        <a href="#">test5</a>
        <a href="#">test6</a>
      </div>        
<div id="slideshow"  class="pics">
<a href="#"><img src="images/1.jpg" alt="#" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="images/2.jpg" alt="#" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="images/3.jpg" alt="#" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="images/4.jpg" alt="#" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="images/5.jpg" alt="#" /></a>
<a href="#"><img src="images/6.jpg" alt="#" /></a>                           
</div>
```

Thanks For all your help
Judith

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption of the conflict can be handles instead of the $ use `jQuery` or alternatively you can use your own custom id so jquery could be set to use jq by do this:

```
var jq=$.noConflict();
```

This means that you can use both jquery and mootools together and not give you problems.

This plugin you found has the option pause to enable pause on hove see [here](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/options.html). so in your case:

```
$(function() {
    $('#slideshow').cycle({
        speed:       200, //timer removed so it cycles automatically.
        pager:      '#nav',
        pause:      1, //pause on hover
        pagerEvent: 'mouseover',
        after: onAfter,
        activePagerClass: 'activeSlide' //Remove comma here
    });
});

//Use this to add/remove styling to your #navs.
function onAfter() { 
 }
```

Also it states each child of your container is a slide so in your case your `<a>` would be a slide i would suggest wrapping it in a div :)